# CMake can't find include file from subfolder

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to add to my CMake project some subfolder which contains some additional functionality. MyProject is a shared library. Ideally it will be fine to just include files from subfolder and to compile all them together. But so far I've found a way only to include that as a static library that suits me too. So my files structure should look like the following:

```
MyProject
    src
        main.cpp
    include
        main.h
    CMakeLists.txt
    3dparty
        SomeFolder
           src
               file.cpp
           include
               file.h
           CMakeLists.txt
```

**MyProject/CMakeLists.txt:**

```rb
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyProject)
file(GLOB SRC . src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB INC . include/*.h)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRC} ${INC})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
add_subdirectory(3dparty/SomeFolder)
```

and **3dparty/SomeFolder/CMakeLists.txt:**

```rb
project (SomeFolder)
file(GLOB SRC . src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB INC . include/*.h)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC} ${INC})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

I can compile the project and I see that compiler produses SomeFolder.a so it looks good. But for some reason I can't include files from `3dparty/SomeFolder/include` in main.*. So far I've tried:

```
#include "file.h"
#include "3dparty/SomeFolder/file.h"
```

but nothing works. I get error: 'file.h' file not found.

What I did wrong? How can I include files from subproject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you forgot to link the sublibrary to your main  library. Usr target_link_libraries()

Comment: Ok, I've added  `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SomeFolder)` to the main CMakeLists.txt and looks that that works. Is that possible to add somehow this line inside `3dparty/SomeFolder/CMakeLists.txt` ? It would be nice to add subfolder with only one instruction only (`add_subdirectory`).

Comment: No, and I believe you're making a few wrong assumptions here. add_subirectory() will do nothing for linking (as you experienced), and the arguments of target_link_libraries() are targets (executable or library), not directory paths. The normal way to link is just to specify the dependencies for each target with target_link_libraries(). If CMake can at some point uniquely identify one of the dependencies as another target, it will know what to do.